# Web API ActionFilter modify returned value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, action-filter

I have a Web API application that I need to get ahold of the return value of some of the API endpoints via an ActionFilter's OnActionExecuted method

I'm using a custom attribute to identify the endpoints that have data that I need to modify, but I can't seem to find the actual result object from within the HttpActionExecutedContext.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can get the returned value through the `Response.Content` property. If your action has returned an object you can cast it to `ObjectContent` from where you can get the actual instance of the returned value:

```cs
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var objectContent = context.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (objectContent != null)
        {
            var type = objectContent.ObjectType; //type of the returned object
            var value = objectContent.Value; //holding the returned value
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The type of `context.Response.Content` is `System.Net.Http.ObjectContent<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model.ViewModels.UserAction>>`.  I just want the `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Model.ViewModels.UserAction>` part.  How do I get that?

Comment: `ObjectContent<T>` is derives form `ObjectContent` so just cast `context.Response.Content` to `ObjectContent` then you can use to `Value` property to cast to your `IEnumerable<Model.ViewModels.UserAction>`...

Comment: This did the job for me. Thanks